# URL rewrite to home page using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking to serve /myweb/index.php file as the default landing page when someone tries to access the domain using myweb.com. I tried using several combinations inside .htaccess but failed to achieve the result.

Another part of the requirement is that other URL redirection shouldn't have a problem due to this particular rewrite url, in other words rest of the url shouldn't look inside /myweb/ to serve images and whatnot.

Right now I have these inside my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^$  myweb/index.php  [L] (This does not)
RewriteRule ^shops/(.*)$ /myweb/shops/$1 [L]   (This works)
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /myweb/content/$1 [L]  (This works)
```

.htaccess file is placed at /var/lib/tomcat7-cms/webapps/ROOT

Anyhelp regarding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just move myweb/* up one directory, or point your web root into myweb?

Comment: myweb is interchangeable, therefore we have several assets placed at the root directory, can you help me out as to how I can make the index.php inside myweb to be the default one? I updated the welcome list but that didn't help.